# django-rest-framework limit the allowed_methods to GET

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I Have just started with django-rest-framework.
Pretty enthousiastic about it, except for the fact there are very little examples available.
getting the api working is going great, but all the extra's is a puzzle.
(adding extra custom fields etc.)

Now I wonder how you can restrict the allowed_methods in for example a ListView or a DetailView.
Adding this to the class in the views.py like I read somewhere as an answer... does not seem to have any effect:

```
allowed_methods = ('GET',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably not relevant anymore based on recent years downvotes.. It was relevant in '12 tho :)**

Django-rest-framework actually have very many examples..

Take a look at http://django-rest-framework.org, http://django-rest-framework.org/contents.html and http://rest.ep.io/ for some good examples and documentation.

If you are designing a REST function by yourself, not using any of the django-rest-framework magic (like rest.ep.io) to generate it for you, you should look into mixin (http://django-rest-framework.org/howto/mixin.html).

If you want to restrict to only get methods. Just use def get(...) and the mixin class.

Example from link provided:

```
curl -X GET http://rest.ep.io/mixin/
```

urls.py

```
from djangorestframework.compat import View
from djangorestframework.mixins import ResponseMixin
from djangorestframework.renderers import DEFAULT_RENDERERS
from djangorestframework.response import Response

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class ExampleView(ResponseMixin, View):
    renderers = DEFAULT_RENDERERS

    def get(self, request):
        response = Response(200, {'description': 'Some example content',
                                  'url': reverse('mixin-view')})
        return self.render(response)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ExampleView.as_view(), name='mixin-view'),
)
```

Comment: Ok, this can be usefull for more complex new views, the answer I was lookin for, I just found out myselve.

Comment: Ah, I missed the rest.ep.io that's a very usefull link! (sorry, to many late nights working on this I Guess)

Comment: By the way, the answer to my original question is in the answer I added myselve, however, this is to usefull not to accept as THE answer, so thanks!

Comment: Good! I have been fiddling a lot with this as well. I also came from the same rest framework that had the allowed_methods (dont remember the name). I am very happy with django-rest-framework. Good luck :)

Answer (score 115):

If you are using ModelViewSet and still want to restrict some methods you can add `http_method_names`.

Example:

```
class SomeModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head']
```

Once you do this, `get`, `post` and `head` will be allowed. But `put`, `patch` and `delete` will not be allowed.

Comment: I like this approach it seems to be more simple, but you have to repeat yourself for each view set. Maybe there is another approach to do this for all viewsets at once. Do you know how?

Comment: I agree. I had expected some constant like ``AllowAllMethods`` equivalent to the ``AllowAny`` permission for example.

Comment: @ePascoal you can create a Viewset class that inherits from the mixins of the http methods you want to allow: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#custom-viewset-base-classes

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for necro, but I stumbled upon this question looking for a similar issue.

I only wanted to allow `retrieve()` but not to `list()`. What I ended up doing:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.exceptions import MethodNotAllowed

from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        raise MethodNotAllowed("GET")
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides the **http_method_names**, there's this solution that Django Rest Framework proposes in here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#custom-viewset-base-classes

It consists on inheriting from **GenericViewSet** instead of **ModelViewSet**, and from the appropiate mixin classes.

If you want a viewset that provides only the **list** and **retrieve** methods (both of them use **GET**), then do this:

```
class ListRetrieveViewSet(
      Viewsets.GenericViewSet,
      mixins.ListModelMixin,  
      mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As almost everything in django-rest-framework, once you find it out, its very simple.
In the urls in stead of using ListOrCreateModelView I had to use ListModelView.