# Django REST Framework that doesn't alter the model data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a middleware web app that will allow users to control some services on our servers. To that end, I have several models created in Django that are used to track things like the current state of the server, or a list of which inputs are valid for any given service.

The API needs to be able to:

- List all instances of a model
- Show detailed information from one instance of a model
- Accept JSON to be converted into instructions for the software (i.e. "This list of outputs should source from this input")

I don't need to have any further access to the data - Any changes to the details of the models will be done by a superuser through the Django admin interface, as it will only change if the software configuration changes.

So far all the DRF documentation I've found assumes that the API will be used to create and update model data - How can I use DRF for just GET calls and custom actions? Or should I forego DRF and just use plain Django, returning JSON instead of HTML?

Edit: I've realised where my confusion was coming from; I was misunderstanding the purpose/function of serializers vs viewsets. Serializers will always have create + update methods because they turn incoming data into a model object. Viewsets determine what can be done with that object, so that's where you enable different access methods.

Comment: Check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly and below to see if you find anything that will serve your need or could be a base for your implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-rest-framework limit the allowed\_methods to GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549867/django-rest-framework-limit-the-allowed-methods-to-get)

Comment: @Pwnosaurus That question covers the GET part, but it doesn't mention custom actions not associated with a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ModelViewSet`, you can use the `http_method_names` class variable.

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use [readonlymodelviewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset), example from docs

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing accounts.
    """
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```