# DRF: how to not allow create() in Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with DRF and have a ViewSet where I want to allow all the possible actions (list, details, update, delete), except `create()`.

This is what I have for the moment:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Foo.objects.order_by('-date_added').all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        version = get_object_or_404(Foo, pk=pk)
        html = request.data.get('html')
        version.update_content(html)
        return Response(data={
            'id': version.id,
            'name': version.name,
            'description': version.description,
            'html': version.content,
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I know I could make the serializer inherit from `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` but then I wouldn't be able to update it.

So what is the cleanest way of not allowing to `create()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31451101/11607969), you can limit the allowed methods by adding `http_method_names` in any class view. http_method_names is an attribute in Django default view class, you can find the detailed definition in [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.http_method_names).

Take your code as an example, if you want to exclude create(refer to 'post' method) operation, you can do the following:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.order_by('-date_added').all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    http_method_names = ['head', 'get', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']
```

Answer (score 1):

from rest framework's code

```
class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
               mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
               mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
               mixins.ListModelMixin,
               GenericViewSet):
```

you can create your viewset without the `CreateModelMixin`

```
class MyViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
               mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
               mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
               mixins.ListModelMixin,
               GenericViewSet):
```