# How to re-use GET call of another class-based api view

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a hard time trying to re-use a `get` call from an existing APIView in another APIVIew.

I have a class-based DRF view:

```
# in urls.py

path('api/something', views.SomethingList.as_view()),
path('api/similarsomething', views.SomethingList.as_view()), #legacy url

# in views.py

class SomethingList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   
    queryset = Something.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomethingSerializer

    # override get, because of some required custom action
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         # do some custom actions (scan folder on filesystem)
         ...
         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The above view both provides a `get` (list) and `post` (create) API interface. As intended. I've augmented it with DRF-spectacular information (not shown here) to generate my swagger docs.

Now, I have another (legacy) URL defined that should do exactly the same as the get (list) call above. Currently, this legacy url also points to the `SomethingList`.
But ... the legacy URL should NOT provide the post (create) interface, and I want to mark it as 'deprecated' in swagger using drf-spectacular. So I figured I need a separate class to restrict to get() and add the `@extend_schema` decorator

So I though of re-using the existing `SomethingList.get` functionality as follows:

```
# in urls.py

path('api/something', views.SomethingList.as_view()),
path('api/similarsomething', views.SimilarSomethingList.as_view()), # ! points to new class

# in views.py

class SomethingList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     ...

class SimilarSomethingList(generics.ListAPIView):     #ListAPIView only!

    @extend_schema(summary="Deprecated and other info..")
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = SomethingList.as_view()
        return view.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, this doesn't work. I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'`
I tried a couple of variations, but couldn't get that working either.

**Question:**
How can I reuse the `get()` call from another APIView? Should be simple, so I'm likely overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Have you tried setting `http_method_names` attribute to the class view? Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31451101/13022138

Comment: @Kyell: That was a good suggestion. I've subclassed from `SomethingList`, inserted `http_method_names = ['get', 'head']` and then added the `get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` method calling `super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)`, and added the `@extend_schema` decorator. If you make your comment in an answer, I will upvote it

Comment: That would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set `http_method_names` to the class view.

```
class SomethingList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head']
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31451101/13022138